# using lightbox - Lokesh Dhakar with magnific popup

Tags: html, css, popup, lightbox, magnific-popup

I am using Lightbox inside a magnific popup (Dialog with CSS animation).

The lightbox images are places inside the magnific popup, and when you SCROLLED down and opened an image, when you click the arrows to go to the next or prev image the screen pops up to the top of the magnific popup. This doesn't happen when using arrows on your keyboard to navigate through pictures. So what is the difference between clickng on your mouse and clicking on your keyboard? And how do i fix this? You can find the bug here http://www.mot08.hr/ostalo.html Click on one of "Više" then scroll down, open an image, and try to click with your mouse the arrows to navigate through images.

Thank you for your time & have a great day.

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix your issue? Post some code.(Using a lightbox inside another lightbox may not be your best option)

Comment: I used a different dialog window popup and that fixed it